# For loop has different values inside vs outside the loop

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am attempting to make a compound interest calculation with a recession in an arbitrary year. The following promise function calculates the development of the variable portfolio.

EDITS FOR CLARITY:

- const `recessions` is an array that cycles recyear from 1 to 20 (`recseverity` is static)
- The ternary (`thisyear == recyear`) triggers in a different year each run, causing a 50% decrease in `portfolio` in different years

```js
const chunk = ( horizon, principal, roi, recyear, recseverity ) => { 
 return new Promise( resolve => {
  // Decimalise and create portfolio holder
  let portfolio = principal
  let crash = 1 - ( recseverity / 100 )
  let grow = 1 + ( roi / 100 )

  // Loop over the years and crash or grow
  for (let thisyear = 1; thisyear < horizon +1; thisyear++) {
   thisyear == recyear ? ( portfolio *= crash ) : ( portfolio *= grow )
   console.log( portfolio )
  }
  console.log( 'last', portfolio )

  // Resolve with the outcome
  resolve( { year: recyear, result: portfolio } )
 } )
}

const horizon = 20
const principal = 100
const roi = 7
const recseverity = 50
const yearlyadd = principal/horizon

const recessions = []
for (let year = 1; year < horizon +1; year++) {
 recessions.push( { year: year, severity: recseverity } )
}

Promise.all( recessions.map( recession => chunk( horizon, principal, roi, recession.year, recession.severity ) ) )
.then( console.log.bind( console ) )
```

The kicker is that everything goes perfect, except that the final outcome of the portfolio variable is a value that makes no sense to me. ALL OF THEM return 180.82637675169082.

I can see in the console.log statements that the for loop works perfectly right up until the last run of the loop, where it suddenly decides 180.82637675169082 is the answer. Which is impossible.

Output of the above:

```js
[ { year: 1, result: 180.82637675169082 },
  { year: 2, result: 180.82637675169082 },
  { year: 3, result: 180.82637675169082 },
  { year: 4, result: 180.82637675169082 },
  { year: 5, result: 180.82637675169082 },
  { year: 6, result: 180.82637675169082 },
  { year: 7, result: 180.82637675169082 },
  { year: 8, result: 180.82637675169082 },
  { year: 9, result: 180.82637675169082 },
  { year: 10, result: 180.82637675169082 },
  { year: 11, result: 180.82637675169082 },
  { year: 12, result: 180.82637675169082 },
  { year: 13, result: 180.82637675169082 },
  { year: 14, result: 180.82637675169082 },
  { year: 15, result: 180.82637675169082 },
  { year: 16, result: 180.82637675169082 },
  { year: 17, result: 180.82637675169082 },
  { year: 18, result: 180.82637675169082 },
  { year: 19, result: 180.82637675169082 },
  { year: 20, result: 180.82637675169082 } ]
```

Looking at the console.log statements it looks like the last run of the loop is what breaks things. The portfolio variable develops fine until the last run, and then it just turns into 180.82637675169082.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something obvious, but why do you need to use a promise here?

Comment: I did it functional before, but then decided to rewrite it as promises to force myself to think in a different pattern. I have the same issue using the functional paradigm...

Comment: I think your misunderstanding how promise is working here. I'm going to write up an example and hopefully it's clear enough for you to realize what's going on.

Comment: The recyear cycles through 1 to 20. It is different every time. The ternary triggers a 50% decrease in portfolio when (thisyear == recyear) which if s different moment each time. This should result in a different outcome every time.

Comment: Sorry, I read the code wrong (thats one examples, why short code is not easier to read). But the question is still the same, why do you expect, that the outcome shoud be different?  For each call of `chunk` there will always be only one `thisyear` that is equal to `recyear`. So you only have one `*=0.5` and the rest is `*=1.07`, but `100 * 0.5 * 1.07 * 1.07` is the same as  `100 * 1.07 * 1.07  * 0.5 ` so the result is the same for all of them (Commutative property of multiplication)

Answer (score 1):

My assumptions were wrong.

I assumed that in a compound interest calculation the year in which the portfolio halves matters.

In real world terms: I assumed that if you invest X amount of money, it matters whether a recession occurs next year or in 10 years.

Turns out it does not.

PBKAC.

Many thanks to those of you who helped me reach this conclusion.

Answer (score 0):

If you analyze your code you'll find that you do the same calculations every time so the result will be the same , look at this line of your code

```
            thisyear == recyear ? ( portfolio *= crash ) : ( portfolio *= grow )
```

the var **thisyear** will equal **recyear** only one time the portfolio will multiply by the crash and this will happen only one time << else the portfolio will multiply by the grow >>

also every variable is the same in every promise except  **recyear**
so nothing will change the result except you change other variables

so finally I hope you notice that  problem

Comment: I was fully aware of this but didn't realise the impact fully. I spent the last 30 mins with a notebook and calculator app. My assumptions were the issue.